# Xcode 4: Trying to build MailCore.Framework for OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, xcode4, mailcore

I've been trying to build MailCore with Xcode 4 for the past couple of days, but I can't seem to get past this one error. Here is the full error:

> PBXCp include/libetpan /Users/kicks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MailCore-drptxcxpvfzzjqhlbxdsrxosqjqq/Build/Products/Debug/include/libetpan
>       cd /Users/kicks/Downloads/MailCore/libetpan/build-mac
>       builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/kicks/Downloads/MailCore/libetpan/build-mac/include/libetpan /Users/kicks/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MailCore-drptxcxpvfzzjqhlbxdsrxosqjqq/Build/Products/Debug/include
>
> **error: /Users/kicks/Downloads/MailCore/libetpan/build-mac/include/libetpan: No such file or directory**

Ok, so my investigation has led me to think that the problem is in the "Build Settings" under the "Search Paths" section. Specifically, the "Header Search Paths." I was thinking that the libetpan directory is not found because Xcode is trying to use the default path to look for the libetpan directory (i.e. ${SRC_ROOT}).

No matter what I put in for the Header Search Path, Xcode doesn't use it and I get the same error.

What am I missing? Is my problem even with the Header Search Paths or is there another setting Im overlooking? I apologize if this is something simple, but Xcode sometimes really eludes me.

This is my exact process:

1. `git clone` the repository located here: https://github.com/jwatson/MailCore. This is a fork of the original because the original produces a lot of errors and warnings in Xcode 4. I also run `git submodule init` and `git submodule update` to install the dependencies.
2. Open MailCore.xcodeproj
3. Try to build the libetpan.a static library.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find a shell script named "update.sh" in the build-mac directory. Just run it there and it will create all the missing directories and configs.

After that the Xcode-project will build.